# При изменении переменной у клона префаба она меняется у всех

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
go = Instantiate(prefab, ceateLoc.position, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 270f));
            go.GetComponent<net>().Start();
            go.GetComponent<net>().layerWeight12 = lw12;
            go.GetComponent<net>().layerWeight23 = lw23;
            go.GetComponent<net>().layerWeight34 = lw34;
            go.GetComponent<net>().firstGeneration = false;
            go.GetComponent<net>().active = false;
            go.tag = "Agent";
            go.name = "car";
            go.GetComponent<net>().mutate = 5;
            go.GetComponent<net>().Initializate();
            go.GetComponent<net>().SetMutatedWeights();
```

Код выше из объекта `despawnController` повторяется 40 раз, и все 40 объектов имеют одинаковую переменную `layerWeight12`.

```
public void Initializate()
    {
        if (firstGeneration)
        {
            SetRandomWeights();
        }
        else
        {
            Rigidbody2D rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.simulated = true;
        }
    }    

public void SetMutatedWeights()
    {
        if (mutate != 0)
        {
            MutateArrRandom(layerWeight12, mutationRate);
            MutateArrRandom(layerWeight23, mutationRate);
            MutateArrRandom(layerWeight34, mutationRate);
        }
        active = true;
    }

    public double[,] MutateArrRandom(double[,] Arr, double mutationFactor)
    {
        double[,] arrc = Arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrc.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < arrc.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (RandomInt(0, 2) == 1)
                {
                    if (RandomInt(0, 2) == 1)
                    {
                        arrc[i, y] = Arr[i, y] + mutationFactor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrc[i, y] = Arr[i, y] - mutationFactor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arrc;
    }
```

Это код из объекта `car(agent)`.

[image: Выбрал все объекты на сцене]

P.s. это только обрывки кода, на скрине я выделил все созданные объекты `car(agent)`

Comment: Чувствуется мне что вы путаете ref val типы.

Comment: Про100 клон может быть не глубоким, а только поверхностным

Comment: А lw12 точно разные? :D

Comment: @Kamushek изначально одинаковые, но потом вызывается SetMutatedWeights(); который случайно изменяет layerWeights в каждом объекте

Answer (score 0):

В методе

```
public void SetMutatedWeights()
    {
        if (mutate != 0)
        {
            MutateArrRandom(layerWeight12, mutationRate);
            MutateArrRandom(layerWeight23, mutationRate);
            MutateArrRandom(layerWeight34, mutationRate);
        }
        active = true;
    }
```

Допущена ошибка, метод `MutateArrRandom` ничего не меняет, а возвращает массив,
который никуда не присваивается.

Скорее всего тут должно быть

```
        layerWeight12 = MutateArrRandom(layerWeight12, mutationRate);
        layerWeight23 = MutateArrRandom(layerWeight23, mutationRate);
        layerWeight34 = MutateArrRandom(layerWeight34, mutationRate);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Операция `GetComponent` дорогая и не должна повторяться.
- `Start` запускается автоматически в следующем фрейме, и его не нужно запускать мануально. Метод исполняющий код при создании это `Awake`.

Присвоения огромного количества публичных полей и вызовов методов ужасает, это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class NetSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Net _netTemplate;
    [SerializeField] private int _netCount = 40;
    [SerializeField] private int _mutate = 5;

    public void Spawn (Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _netCount; i++) {
            GameObject NewNet = Instantiate(_netTemplate.gameObject, position, rotation);
            // если бесит клон в имени
            NewNet.name = _netTemplate.gameObject.name;
            // тег можно и в самом префабе указать
            NewNet.GetComponent<Net>().Setup(lw12, lw23, lw34, _mutate);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
// если обязательное, то указываем
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

// Net ужасное имя, кто ты, что ты, не понятно
public class Net : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool Active { get; private set; }
    [SerializeField] private float _mutationOffset = 0.1f;
    private Rigidbody _body;
    private float[,] _layerWeight12;
    private float[,] _layerWeight23;
    private float[,] _layerWeight34;
    
    private void Awake () {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void Setup (float[,] lw12, float[,] lw23, float[,] lw34, int mutate, bool isFirstGeneration = false, bool active = false) {
        _layerWeight12 = lw12;
        _layerWeight23 = lw23;
        _layerWeight34 = lw34;
        Active = active;
        Initializate(isFirstGeneration);
        SetMutatedWeights(mutate, _mutationOffset);
    }

    private void Initializate (bool isFirstGeneration) {
        if (isFirstGeneration)
            SetRandomWeights();
        else
            _body.simulated = true;
    }

    public void SetMutatedWeights (int mutate, float offset) {
        if (mutate != 0) {
            MutateLayerWeith(_layerWeight12, offset);
            MutateLayerWeith(_layerWeight23, offset);
            MutateLayerWeith(_layerWeight34, offset);
        }
        Active = true;
    }

    private void MutateLayerWeith (float[,] weith, float mutationOffset) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Насколько я понял вы с вероятностью в 50% меняете элемент на некий +/- отступ.

Для чего схематоз с изменением массива который ссылается на исходный и его возвратом, который возвращается в никуда, не понятно.

Нужна ли точность `double`, я тоже сомневаюсь !?%

Просто меняем, то с чем работаем:

```
private void MutateLayerWeith (float[,] weith, float mutationOffset) {
    for (int x = 0; x < weith.GetLength(0); x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < weith.GetLength(1); y++)
            if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 1) {
                if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 1)
                    weith[x, y] += mutationOffset;
                else
                    weith[x, y] -= mutationOffset;
            }
}
```